# Rails2 to Rails3 routing conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Routing makes zero sense to me, is there an easy way to convert this:

```
#map.resources :bicycles, :controller => 'store/bicycles', :path_prefix => 'store'
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `controller` option is also available in [***Rails 3***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) and the `path_prefix` can be achieved with `scope`. The below is the conversion of the route to ***Rails 3***

```
scope 'store' do
  resources :bicycles, :controller => 'store/bicycles'
end
```